# Funcion NOW(),localtime(), etc en servidor MySql esta adelantada

Tags: mysql, servidor, mysql-workbench

Cuando uso cualquiera de esto en el localhost funciona correctamente me trae la hora de que debe ser pero cuando las uso en el servidor me trae 1h adelantada, ¿Alguien sabe porque pasa esto y como puedo solucionarlo?

LOCALHOST:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SERVIDOR:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Sucede porque el servidor de la base de datos está en distinto uso horario, puedes ajustar este con `set timezone` antes de las `querys`, o bien cambiar la franja horaria al servidor.

En el ejemplo se muestra la hora antes y después de ajustarlo con `set timezone`.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT NOW();

| NOW()               |
| ------------------- |
| 2020-04-27 13:32:29 |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SET time_zone='Europe/Madrid';
```

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT NOW();

| NOW()               |
| ------------------- |
| 2020-04-27 15:32:29 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Buenas, cuando quiero usar el SET time_zone='Europe/Madrid'  me sale error, sabes porque?
> 1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Europe/Madrid' , tengo la version 8.0.19

Comment: Parece que según el mysql puede tener o no las tablas de timezone, si da error es porque no tiene la zona o la tabla, te paso un enlace con información https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-g11n-excerpt/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html. Si tiene la tabla con esta query puedes ver las zonas horarias que reconoce: SELECT * FROM mysql.time_zone_name; y seleccionar una con el mismo horario.